# How to add space in PHP

Tags: php, echo

```
echo "<h1 class='price'>" . $currency . round( $price['daily'] ) . "</h1>";
```

Is there a way to print empty space before currency?

Edit: The above code gives me **From₹3880** in my theme. But I want **From $3880** with a space

PS: Noob here

Answer (score 2):

Use the non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) HTML entity:

```
echo "<h1 class='price'>&nbsp;" . $currency . round( $price['daily'] ) . "</h1>";
```

Answer (score 1):

h1 is a block-level element. Unless you've modified its style, it will have some margin and padding from the browser by default. So, adding a space here doesn't make sense. Fix it in CSS, don't abuse HTML for layout.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a space inside the quotes should do the trick.

```
echo "<h1 class='price'> " . $currency . round( $price['daily'] ) . "</h1>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<h1 class='price'> {$currency} ". round( $price['daily'] ) . "</h1>";
```

or better still use

```
echo "<h1 class='price'> &nbsp;" . $currency . round( $price['daily'] ) . "</h1>";
```

Go through  the following link

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp